# Is it possible to reverse the order in which python's standard logging package checks logging level priority

Tags: python, logging

Python gives high priority to logging levels with higher priority value and low priority to levels with low priority. I want to reverse this. Is is possible ?

Scenario : We have a number of applications already in our Server (not done in python). Also, we have been using 9 logging levels so far.

```
*emergency = 0,
alert = 1,
critical = 2,
error = 3,
warning = 4,
notice = 5,
info = 6,
debug = 7,
trace = 8,
verbose = 9*
```

This has been the standard followed. As you can see the priority decreases as level value increase in our standard. If possible, We would like to continue using this standard but python looks at logging priority in the opposite order. What is the best solution ?

Comment: can you show how you set up your logging levels

Comment: Why do you refer to the numeric values of the levels? You should you the names instead of any implementation details. If this conflicts with your server code, you should asks how to solve the concrete problem.

Comment: That's 10 levels.

Answer (score 0):

This is not worth doing. The idea of severity in the logging package is baked in as higher values = more severe, and the opposite sense won't work as expected.

The way round that Python implements logging levels is the same as Java, C# and other systems: higher value = more severe.